# Why does Django _meta store fields and many_to_many fields separately?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am a beginner in django/python.I am using `_meta` to access the fields of a django model. I use `_meta.fields` to access the **fields** and `_meta.many_to_many` to access the **many_to_many fields**. What are the reasons that makes django store the fields so separately? It could be that the many_to_fields are included in the fields itself and the type specified as `ManyToManyField` or something that is more appropriate.

Guidance would be highly appreciated by a beginner. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the fields have some differencies:

- "normal" field can be retrireved with simple query, while m2m field needs JOIN;
- m2m field can have (and has) intemediate model to connect through, "normal" field can't;
- "normal" field just returns single object, m2m field returns queryset.

Comment: Hi, DrTyrsa. Firstly, thank you for your efforts. I totally agree with you. What I want to know is when we just want the names of all the fields in the model, why there comes the difference?

Comment: @SandipAgarwal What I want to know is why not to use `_meta.get_all_field_names()` when you want the names of all the fields in the model?

Comment: It gives the `reverse relation names` as well. [Reference Link](http://django-model-internals-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/get_all_field_names.html)

Comment: @SandipAgarwal And? What is the problem? Just iterate over `_meta.fields` and `_meta.many_to_many` if you don't want them. There are enough reasons to store them separately and `Meta` objects doesn't have (and why it should) a method to "get all fileds names, including m2m fields, but not including reverse relation names".